# velodyne_driver test for ROS hydro?

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-hydro, velodyne-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS groovy the Velodyne packages are saved in /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/velodyne/ velodyne_Driver or velodyne_msgs or velodyne_pointcloud. Each velodyne directory has subdirectories bin, launch, src, lib, and test!

But in ROS hydro the velodyne files are divided in directory /opt/ros/hydro/  shared, or lib, or include. Without a commun directory of the velodyne stack. But, where are the velodyne test? Aren't there in hydro version?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141631/velodyne_driver-test-for-ros-hydro?/) by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Hydro requires released binaries to use the newer catkin build tools.

The different file layout is an effort to follow the Linux Filesysterm Hierarchy Standard. [REP-0122](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html) documents the layout, along with the [motivation for making those changes](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html#motivation).

Unfortunately, the current ROS packaging tools do not install unit tests. To build and run them, you must check out the package sources into a catkin workspace.

For the Velodyne driver, the source repository is here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne.git. The current Hydro release version has the `velodyne-1.1.2` tag. The `master` branch may include unreleased updates. You are welcome to use that, but it is not as thoroughly tested as an official release.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on 2014-03-20**:
I previously understood I could use catkin or rosbuild to build a package. In hydro, I can use just catkin right?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-03-20**:
No, for packages you are not going to release using the ROS buildfarm you can use "catkin" or "rosbuild" - in Groovy, in Hydro, in Indigo and likely even in any upcoming distro afterwards. But if you want to release your package using the ROS farm to create Debian packages it must be a "catkin" package as of Hydro.